# Exponential CD burn times in iTunes 10.6.1 (7) on OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, itunes, imac, cd-burning

The more I try put on a CD and the closer I get to the 80 minute mark, the longer it takes to burn with it on occasion never finishing, the time rises exponentially. I never try and burn more than 80 minutes (not sure it will let you anyway).

Is this a known issue?

I'm using the standard 'burn from playlist' method.

Also sometimes it goes nuts and starts generating random 'time remaining' times, changing every couple of seconds (see below).

[image: itunes exponential cd burn times going haywire]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc#Storage_capacity_and_playing_time), the original playing time of an audio CD is 74 minutes.

Longer play durations are achieved by "squeezing" the data tracks closer together. Also, because CDs are written from the inside out, the write speed is much faster on the outer sides of the disc — bigger diameter means more distance travelled in the same time.

So squeezing plus faster writing needs more precision. It’s likely that an older CD writer will struggle (on a pre-OS-level) with the precision requirements, leading to claims of absurd burning times. I think you will be on the safe side when burning shorter CDs. I hope this helps!

Comment: It bombs out whatever speed is selected, yes I understand the issue with it becoming exponentially more difficult to put more data on a CD but what I'm on about seems to occur regardless

Comment: The way I read your question, you are asking if putting more data on a CD is increasing burn times. Is that still correct?

Comment: No I'm well within the known limits but as you can see from the screenshot, the burn time is bonkers

Comment: Obviously it is not a common issue, otherwise I would not be the only one answering your question. Most probably your CD writer / DVD combo drive is on its way out. Sorry I can not help you any further.